# Graphic card making the PC case give shocks

Tags: graphics-card

The scenario is the following, I've a Radeon x1650 Pro (AGP) which has not given me any problems so far, until a month or so.

When I touch my case (sitting on a wood table) it gives me shocks, even if I disconnect the power cable. The only thing that remains connected is the monitor cable and when I disconnect it the shocks are gone.

Now, with everything disconnected, when I connect the component video cable from the graphic card to the TV i get a "Wiring Problem" warning and a garbage image.

I think it's the graphic card, if so, what it could be?

PS: All the readings from the power supply (+12v, 5v, etc) are ok, tested them with a multimeter instead of software.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not the graphics card, it's the power supply in either the computer or monitor.

Either the PC PSU has failed and the case it no longer earthed, but connected to live (possibly through a shorted capacitor) or the PSU in the monitor has failed and it's ground is floating high.

The screen of the graphics cable connects the computer case to the monitor's ground.

You should also check the groundign on the sockets the PC = monitor are plugged into

Comment: And since the shocks go away when he disconnects the monitor, I think it's safe to say that's his source.  But an extra +1 for also recommending to check the outlets.